# error "NameError: uninitialized constant Spree::ThemeSupport" while using spree_import_products gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, spree

in my app , I am using spree gem. Now for product importing ,i used spree_import_products gem.

`first i add "gem 'import_products', :git => 'git://github.com/joshmcarthur/spree-import-products.git'`

then bundle install" in gem file.then run bundle install, it successfully installed. then run "rake import_products:install".but it shows **error** like this....

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Spree::ThemeSupport
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/spree-import-products-2bcca17f140f/lib/import_products_hooks.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/spree-import-products-2bcca17f140f/lib/import_products.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
```

how to resolve this...

Answer (score 0):

You can check [here](https://github.com/joshmcarthur/spree-import-products/blob/master/import_products.gemspec) that this extension requires a very old version of Spree and Ruby. It does not have tests. The problem is the extension itself. Look for another extension or implementing yourself.